# Printing specific rows SAS

Tags: sas

I'm very new to SAS and I'm having trouble nailing some of its concepts down(I'll be using the native example table BASEBALL for this question).  So what I'm doing is making two new columns for the table which are the batavg86 and batavgcr shown below(I believe they work just fine) and then printing specific columns of the table(name, batavg86, team, and salary) if the value batavg86 is greater than or equal to .300.  What I have posted below does not work, it just prints the whole table.  Can someone explain this to me because I'm pretty lost(My professor started us on this language and then went out of town for two weeks).

```
data mybaseball;
    set sashelp.baseball;
    batavg86 = nHits/nAtBat;
    batavgcr = crHits/CrAtBat;
    proc print data = name,batavg86,team,salary;
    where batavg86 => .300;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the results you're looking for:

```
data mybaseball;
    set sashelp.baseball;
    batavg86 = nHits/nAtBat;
    batavgcr = crHits/CrAtBat;
run;

proc print data = mybaseball;
  var name batavg86 team salary;
  where batavg86 >= .300;
run;
```